# gnuplot boxes with different color bars

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I want to plot a histogram like chart with boxes. And I hope the bars have different colors. I found some previous cases, use `lc rgb variable`, but it doesn't work for me. My version is limited to gnuplot4.2. Here is my data sheet:

```
stage          11402.364    100%    1
App1              78.552    0.69%   2
App2           11323.812    99.30%  2
Read               8.469    0.07%   3
Write             41.285    0.04%   3
Repeat          5748.351    50.41%  3
Count           4933.746    43.27%  3
Count_1         3841.355    33.69%  4
Count_2         1092.391    9.59%   4
```

Here is the code part:

```
set boxwidth 0.5 relative 
set style fill solid 0.5
set xtics rotate
plot 'histogramdata_2.txt' using 2:xtic(1):4 with boxes variable lc rgb variable notitle
```

I want to use the 4th column to denote the bar color. The document said the third number used in `using` is just the color variable. But it doesn't work for me, the result is no bar produced.

It seems that the `using`  part is quite flexible. I even find some cases in this site put 4 column numbers after using.
It is related to different versions?

Comment: The number of values used for `using` mainly depends on the plotting style. And the `xtic` part must always come last.

Answer (score 9):

Your `plot` command seems to be wrong. Try the following:

```
set boxwidth 0.5 relative 
set style fill solid 0.5
set xtics rotate
plot 'histogramdata_2.txt' using 0:2:4:xticlabels(1) with boxes lc variable
```

It should look like this:

[image]

In short about the `using 0:2:4:xticlabels(1)` part:

- `0` tells gnuplot to place bars (x value) in the same order as they appear on the file
- `2` tells gnuplot to take y values from column 2
- `4` tells gnuplot to take the color variable from the 4th column
- `xticlabels(1)` tells gnuplot to take the text labels for the bars from column 1

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me. It said "undefined variable: variable". So maybe it works for your version. My version is limited to 4.2.

Comment: You might have hit a dead end here. I have been fiddling with 4.2 and it seems `variable` can only be used for sizes, I failed to make it work with colors. My recommendation is that you upgrade your gnuplot if that is possible for you.

Comment: In version 4.2, the third number in using is the boxwidth. So if I follow your method "0:2:4:xtics(1)", the produced bar chart is same color but with different width.

Comment: @baoqger If you only have a few different line colors, you can write the plot commands manually: `plot 'histogramdata_2.txt' using ($4 == 1 ? $0 : 1/0):2:xtic(1) with boxes lc 1, '' using ($4 == 2 ? $0 : 1/0):2:xtic(1) with boxes lc 2, ...`. No, you cannot loop, because in 4.2 that wasn't possible. Or you could use an external script which generates the plot command: `cmd = system('generateplot.sh histogramdata_2.txt'); eval(cmd)`.

Comment: Yes, I only need 4 colors. I also once think about similar method. But not sure. In `($4 == 1 ? $0 : 1/0)` , I can understand only a part, it means if $4 equals to 1 then $0 equals to 1 elso $0 equals to 0? What's that mean?

Comment: Does column `0` refer to the first column in the data file or is that column `1`?

Comment: Column 0 gives you the line number in the file (skipping comments and blank lines)